# How to pass varible value in a webrequest URL?

Tags: c#, ssis, servicenow

Here is my code

```
 WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://satellite.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_query=opened_atBETWEENjavascript:gs.dateGenerate('2016-07-01','00:00:00')@javascript:gs)=.dateGenerate('2016-08-31','23:59:59')");
```

Here instead of date '2016-07-01' i want to pass variable or string and pass theough that link. How can i achive this in c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// 5 days ago
DateTime variableDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5);
// format it however you want
string variableDateText = variableDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

// concatenate it into your string
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://satellite.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_query=opened_atBETWEENjavascript:gs.dateGenerate('" + variableDateText + "','00:00:00')@javascript:gs)=.dateGenerate('2016-08-31','23:59:59')");
```

There are already many related questions about this that you can search for.

Comment: Thank you , It was very helpful